# AWS Session Manager Raspberry-pi/Beaglebone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, raspberry-pi, beagleboneblack, amazon-systems-manager

I am trying to manage a *Beaglebones/Raspberry-pis* using *AWS System Manager*.
I registered it on the AWS System Manager shown in the pic below.

[image]

However, it does not appear in the *Session Manager* tab
[image]

In the *Manage Instances* tab I can try the *Start Session* action.
[image]

When I try to start the session like the image above, I get the error shown below which is not all that helpful.

[image]

**Does anyone know how to make the session manager work with hardware like beaglebones or raspberry-pis? Would it be a matter that AWS would only support Sessions with EC2 instances? Or maybe it is incompatible with the Beaglebone/Raspberry?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Session Manager currently only supports connections to EC2 instances. On-premises managed instances (which is what a Raspberry is after it's registered) are not supported by Session Manager today.

Other features of AWS Systems Manager will work - you can, for example, use Run Command to execute actions on your Raspberry instance.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, @Mats Lannér